# Is there a std::bitset equivalent (or similar) in Java?

Tags: java

I am looking for a c++ std::bitset equivalent or a similar functionality implementation in Java (1.6 specifically). I tried java.util.BitSet but I am finding that it is not quite similar.

The operations I need are the usual bitwise operations such as AND, OR, etc. If possible, I'd like to be able to set the length of the bitset dynamically (which is unsupported in std::bitset). Can anyone provide a recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: What features are you missing from java.util.Bitset that makes you unable to use it?

Comment: It seems like there isn't a way to dynamically retrieve the length of the bitset

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? BitSet.length() certainly seems to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what problem you'd have with the normal [Bitset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.

The bitset is dynamically grown if necessary (with length() returning the pos of the higehst one bit), so that's basically a fool proof solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

i don't know how std::bitset work, but you can use bitwise operator in Java and C++ similary